# How create a local network for docker?

Tags: docker, networking, devops

guys! I'm very need your help! What I must to do(step-by-step), for correct creation of the network interface, for Docker, with my own subnet(192.168.0.0/24)? When I'm trying to create it, my hole network going down or incorrect network interface come back after docker's restart! Can't escape of it!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You want the container to run on your home/work network? Or is this a new network just for your containers?

Comment: @EstebanGarcia I want use them in my local existing network, I have host server, but now I wanna practice in VmwareWorkstation, before installing docker on the host server

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I think I understand what you need. You want to have multiple container in your host each with a unique IP address from your host network.

Now, I haven't test this but this is what you should do:

1. Remove the IP Address from your host network interface

   `$ sudo ip addr del <IP>/24 dev <interface_name>`
2. Create a docker network using a bridge to your host interface

   `$ sudo docker network create --driver bridge --subnet=<your_subnet>/24 --gateway=<here_the_ip_you_deleted_before> --opt "com.docker.network.bridge.name"="docker1" net_name`
3. Add the interface to the just created bridge

   `$ sudo brctl addif docker1 <interface_name>`

Now you can create a container, attach it to the created network and assign an IP from your subnet to it.

```
$ docker run --net net_name --ip <ip_you_want> -ti ubuntu:16.04
```

Comment: but if I want for example install web-server and  databases.. I need unique ip address for this things

Comment: Then I would need you to give me some details on what are you trying to accomplish. You want to have several container on a host with each container having a unique ip assigned statically by you or the dhcp on your network ?

Comment: Yes, some containers on host server, on which I can install something for local using. I have dhcp-server, but will be better to set static ip addresses.

Comment: @Stefan I've edited the answer with something I think will suit your needs.

Comment: When trying to use this command ip addr del <IP>/24 dev <interface_name> get the next error: "Error: either "local" is duplicate, or "ens32" is a garbage."

Comment: ip addr del 192.168.0.157/24 dev ens32

Comment: I removed totally docker-engine, then all of your steps were successful, but internet go down.